# How can I update diskless installation 11.04 to 11.10

Tags: boot, upgrade, nfs, pxe

Bonjour messieurs,

we have installed on our Ubuntu server 64bit in directory /MNT the distribution of Ubuntu 11.04 32 bit as shared drive for PXE diskless computers in school.

1. Can we upgrade to 11.10? How?
2. Can we use NFS 4.0? Is it recommended?
3. Can we use Ubuntu software center and install packages with the GUI?
4. Is possible to use 1 Gbit connection between NFS PXE server and diskless computers?

I'm not Linux expert, but I hope it is possible. Our admin said, do not use GUI packager in 11.04, there is some NFS LOCKING problem. I hope that 11.10 is the general solution.
In the fact, we have HDDs in all computers and we are using them for swapping only. The idea is to have only one installation for all computers in the school for easier servicing.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an upgrade that should not be done blindly - if you break that install then no computer in your school will be able to boot!

I don't see any reason 11.10 wouldn't work where 11.04 did for a PXE/NFS server setup. I would try doing a fresh install into a new directory and exporting that to a couple of clients first to check compatibility.

If it works, it sounds like you would want to chroot into /mnt and use `do-release-upgrade` to update it. But it's quite difficult to answer this properly without full technical details.

To point 2) I'm aware of no problems with NFS4 for this kind of setup, it is the currently accepted de-facto standard.

To point 4) 1Gb is no problem for an PXE/NFS server so long as your hardware supports it.